# Return after posting to before page (graph api facebook php sdk)

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

**CLOSED**

Just remove

```
echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
```

and

```
 change define('REDIRECT_URI
```

Hello this is my first question and i have some problem with facebook graph api.
I make application for update status from my site in canvas page.
this is the code

```
define('APP_ID', 'numbernumbernumber');
define('APP_SECRET', 'codecodecode');
define('REDIRECT_URI', 'canvaspagecanvanvaspage');
define('SCOPE','publish_actions,publish_stream');

require 'includes/php-sdk/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => APP_ID,
        'secret' => APP_SECRET,
        'cookie' => true,
        'display' => 'touch'
    ));

$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

$user = $facebook->getUser();
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

if ($user) {
try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
}
}

$auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=". APP_ID . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode(REDIRECT_URI)."&scope=".SCOPE;

$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = @explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
}
$access_token=$data["oauth_token"];
```

and in html doc :

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/id_ID/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=numbernumbernumber";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div class="fb-login-button" autologoutlink="true"  onlogin="require('./log').info('onlogin callback')" data-show-faces="false" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div><br >

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?message&access_token=<? echo $access_token ?>" method="post">

<br/>Write your status : 
<input name="message" type="text" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Kirim" /><br/></form>
```

1. After posting status success, canvas (or iframe in canvas not return again)
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AZ7N.jpg ->posting success
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZbPX.jpg -> but canvas page ?
   please help me....
2. If i open canvas page, it open canvas page....If i open link to my site, its always redirect to canvas page. please help me for not redirect to canvas page. 
   thanks

Comment: check your fb app setting, canvas url

Answer (score 0):

May you give me the link to see how it works now?

And if your working on a canvas page, you can not leave the canvas page, if you want to send them to your site, you need to do it opening a new window.